# Are Banach spaces complete with their weak uniform structures?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, uniform-spaces

For any Banach space $X$ one has a family of semi-norms:
$$\{\|\cdot\|_{x^*}\mid x^*\in X^*\}\qquad \|x\|_{x^*}=|x^*(x)|$$
these semi-norms induce the *weak* topology on $X$. But they also induce a uniform structure.

> Are Banach spaces with this weak uniform structure complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For an example, let $X=\ell^2$ and consider the sequence $x_n=(1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots)$ with $n$ entries equal to $1$. This is a weak Cauchy sequence which does not converge.

As far as I remember, only finite-dimensional Banach spaces can be weakly complete.